# Magento 2 - Calling Custom Media Attribute

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, php-7

I am trying to call a custom media attribute, and it is assigned to the product; thus I created size guide phtml and I hooked it to the product view, but I ended up with an undefined error "**Undefined variable: _product**"

```
<?php
    $imageHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
    $attributeImage = $_product->getCustomAttribute('sizechart_desktop');
    $attributeImageUrl = $imageHelper->init($_product, 'sizechart_desktop')->setImageFile($attributeImage->getValue())->getUrl();
?>
<div id="sizeGuideModal" class="modal">
    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content centered">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <img src="<?php echo $attributeImageUrl; ?>" />
        </div>
        <!-- <div class="modal-footer">
            <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
        </div> -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And finally, I figured this out :), so I had to add this snippet code to be able to access to the right data:

```
$this->pluginLocator = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$block = $this->pluginLocator->get('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description');
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
$_product = $block->getProduct();
```

The final code looks like this:

```
<?php

$this->pluginLocator = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$block = $this->pluginLocator->get('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description');
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
$_product = $block->getProduct();
$productImageAttr = $_product->getCustomAttribute( 'sizechart_desktop' );
$productImage = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image')
    ->init($_product, 'sizechart_desktop')
    ->setImageFile($productImageAttr->getValue());

?>

<div id="sizeGuideModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content centered">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <img src="<?php echo $productImage->getUrl(); ?>" />
    </div>
    <!-- <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div> -->
  </div>

</div>
```

I hope this will benefit someone at some point.